# Time between jQuery add/remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set a timer, 10 sec in between this?

```
addClass('loading').removeClass('loading')
```

This is the full code

```
$("#loadmore").click(function() {
    cap += 10;
}).bind('click', loadfeed).addClass('loading').removeClass('loading');
```

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to remove the `loading` class after `loadfeed` has completed whatever it is doing, rather than after an arbitrary number of seconds?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp). Also not sure why you are binding to click twice in two different ways... so with those two changes it'd look something like this:

```
$("#loadmore").click(function() {
    cap += 10;
    loadfeed();
    $(this).addClass("loading");
    that = this
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(that).removeClass('loading');
    }, 10000)
});
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [jQUery delay() method](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and create a new [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) item to do the act of removing the class.

```
$("#loadmore").click(function () {
    cap += 10;
    loadfeed();
}).addClass("loading").delay(10000).queue(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("loading");
    $(this).dequeue();
});
```

If you don't like this, the `setTimeout()` solution that @jcmoney provided is awesome.

Comment: beat me to the answer by 18 secs :)

Comment: @bcm... sorry :) but I guess someone doesn't like it :/

Comment: AFAIK `addClass()` and `removeClass()` don't use the jQuery queue system, so `delay()` won't work alone here. In order to use `delay()`, you need to manually add the `removeClass()` to the queue using `queue()`.

Comment: @Hristo Sure thing. It would be nice if `delay()` worked for arbitrary function calls in a jQuery chain, but at least there's a way to work around it. :)

Comment: @Xenethyl... maybe in a future version of jQuery :) anyway, learned something new. this is a good day!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {                      
  $('.letsGo').click(function() { 
    $('.footerCta').addClass('ball');  
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.footerCta').removeClass('ball');
    }, 1000)
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.